# In all browsers "Object doesn't support property or method 'ajaxSubmit'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-forms-plugin

I got the following piece of code, but it always gives me an error saying "Object doesn't support property or method 'ajaxSubmit'". I am not sure where is my error... Can anyone help me?

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.color.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({ height: 0, width: 0, 'overflow': 'hidden' });
    var fileInput = $(':file').wrap(wrapper);
    $('#BTN_Upload').click(function () {
        fileInput.click();
    }).show();
    $("#INPUT_Upload").change(function () {
        var options = {
            target: '#DIV_UploadedImages',
            beforeSubmit: showRequest,
            success: showResponse,
            dataType: "json",
            clearForm: true,
            resetForm: true
        };
        $('#FORM_ImageUpload').ajaxSubmit(options);
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <form id="FORM_ImageUpload" method="post" action="~/Async/UploadImage">
    <input type="file" value="Post" id="INPUT_Upload">
    <img src="~/Images/button_add_pictures.jpg" id="BTN_Upload" class="ProfileButton" />
 </form>
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I have used the scenario in the plugin website and I have used it correctly.

Comment: are you sure jquery.form.js is loaded successfully? I mean no 404 error

Comment: I managed to find it through the debugging tools. The same happened when I loaded it with the online copy of the plugin.

Comment: try this `alert($('#FORM_ImageUpload').ajaxForm);`. What does it alerts?

Comment: What does your form markup look like? That kind of error would imply that #FORM_ImageUpload isn't a proper form.

Comment: alert($('#FORM_ImageUpload').ajaxForm); shows undefined

Comment: try to open in your browser `http://<yoursite.com>/Scripts/jquery.form.js`, where `<yoursite.com>` is your own domain. what can you see?

Comment: or try to write `scripts` in lowercase

Comment: the link opens the js file. the actual directories are not with lowercase, that's why I am trying to keep things the same everywhere.

Comment: and what does `alert($.fn.ajaxSubmit)` outputs?

Comment: alert($.fn.ajaxSubmit) returns undefined.

Comment: it seems like .js file you load is not valid. You say you already tried to include this file remotely? http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js

Comment: Yes, the response is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am new with MVC and I completely forgot that MVC automatically adds jquery to its designs I have included another link to it in the code which caused the issue.

To summarize: If you have linked twice jquery jquery-form will not work.

Answer (score 1):

When I face situations when something doesn't work and I can't understand why, I usually write a minimal required code that works. And then I add code more and more until it stops to work. This is how I find the problem place in my code.

Here is a minimum of code that **should** work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>

alert($.fn.ajaxSubmit);

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

It alerts the source code of `ajaxSubmit` method. You may add parts of your code until it alerts `undefined`, then you'll find out why it doesn't work.

I always use this approach.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I understand that, but that is exactly my issue. That even the bare launch gives me undefined. No matter how I try I can't understand why it's undefined.